# Returning multiples of the same model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, models

I understand this may be similar to the question  [returning and using multiple models in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206071/returning-and-using-multiple-models-in-mvc)

however in that question they are referring to two different models, I am only using one model(Person) and want to return multiples of it

I am building an organisation chart application in c# MVC using a single DB table and model called Person

```
public partial class ActionResult
{
    public string UniqueUserID{ get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string ReportToUniqueUserID { get; set; }
}
```

In my index view

```
<a asp-controller="Person" asp-action="Orgchart" asp-route-id="@item.Adid">OrgChart </a>
```

in my Person Controller

```
public IActionResult Orgchart(string id)
{
    // get myself

    var clickedperson = _context.Person
    .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Adid == id);

    //get my Parent
    var Parent= _context.Person
    .SingleOrDefault(m => m.Adid == id);

    //get all of my childern
    var child = _context.Person
    .Where(b => b.ReportToAdid == id)

    return View("OrgChart");
}
```

Right now I want to be able to get the single Parent of the clicked person and the multiple children of the clicked person and be able to access these from within the view in order to build the organisation chart.

Since they are all the same model(Person) can I even do that?

What is the correct way to access ClickedPerson, Parent and Child from within the view?

Comment: Do have another go at formatting that code. It's a mess now.

Comment: Short answer: create a ViewModel.

Comment: As for your edit: that doesn't change anything. Create a ViewModel to hold the `Self`, `Parent` and `Children`, assign these in the controller and render them in the view. Alternatively you could return a `List<Person>` and assume the first is the self, the second the parent and the remainder are the children, but that's far from maintainable.

Comment: Many thanks, I will look into ViewModel